# DLL providing QWidget over C API

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I have a Qt main application which dynamically loads DLLs with a C API. I can't use Qt plugins, since a few DLLs are pure C.

Now I want the possibility for a DLL to make the main Qt application open a window, decorate it and add a QWidget provided by the DLL.

I'm afraid that if I just push it through as a void* and add it as a QWidget, the main application will try to free it when the window closes which would probably result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why don't you just pass a callback function which creates the QWidget to the DLL?

Comment: So a few DLLs are pure C, can't you load them outside the Qt plugin system?

Comment: @user1095108 They are all supposed to use the same API and I don't want to write it twice. They mostly only implement part of the API, e.g. the C DLLs won't implement the Qt hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is whether the main application links to Qt dynamically or statically. If dynamically, that resolves the issue of static data sharing (since it will mostly reside in the DLL).

Without more details, I'd just say "try it" and see what breaks.

Comment: It links dynamically. Actually not a bad idea to just give it a shot, especially since I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: It actually seems to work. I don't know how or why, but it does.
I create the QWidget inside of the DLL and pass it to the main application which puts it inside a window. I can even call 
    reinterpret_cast<QWidget*>(widget->parent())->close();
from inside the DLL (reacting to button presses). I don't think there's a memory leak, it doesn't die, it just seems to work for some reason. Thanks :)